# Understanding Behavior of Editing aList withing a List

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list containing information and 7 data sets that I will be processing independently.

This list contains the following

```
print header
[['Specimen_RawData_1.csv' '' '' '' '']
['Time' 'Extension' 'Load' 'Strain' 'True Strain']
['(s)' '(mm)' '(N)' '(%)' '(%)']]
```

Now I want to create a list with 7 of these entries and edit some of the values withing it. Specifically replace and empty string with *'Cycle:' + number corresponding to the dataset*.

Here is how I am trying to do it.

I have the list that I am trying to copy and edit

```
header
```

I copy it to a temporary variable

```
tempHeader
```

Then I make some changes to the content of the list tempHeader

Then I append the temporary variable to

```
newHeader


newHeader = []
for i in range(len(dirChange_index)/2):
    tempHeader =[]
    tempHeader = header
    # Want to replace a locaton in the list with the value Cycle i
    tempHeader[0][1] = 'Cycle: ' + str(i+1)
    print tempHeader
print '--'
    newHeader.append([tempHeader])    
print newHeader
```

This shows me that I am successfully changing the value in the temporary list.

```
[['Specimen_RawData_1.csv' 'Cycle: 1' '' '' '']
['Time' 'Extension' 'Load' 'Strain' 'True Strain']
['(s)' '(mm)' '(N)' '(%)' '(%)']]

[['Specimen_RawData_1.csv' 'Cycle: 2' '' '' '']
['Time' 'Extension' 'Load' 'Strain' 'True Strain']
['(s)' '(mm)' '(N)' '(%)' '(%)']]
```

.
.
.

```
[['Specimen_RawData_1.csv' 'Cycle: 7' '' '' '']
['Time' 'Extension' 'Load' 'Strain' 'True Strain']
['(s)' '(mm)' '(N)' '(%)' '(%)']]
```

The behavior I do not understand is that when I append the temporary variable to the growing list, it replaces all of the previous values as well.

```
print newHeader
[[array([['Specimen_RawData_1.csv', 'Cycle: 7', '', '', ''],
   ['Time', 'Extension', 'Load', 'Strain', 'True Strain'],
   ['(s)', '(mm)', '(N)', '(%)', '(%)']], 
  dtype='|S26')], [array([['Specimen_RawData_1.csv', 'Cycle: 7', '', '', ''],
   ['Time', 'Extension', 'Load', 'Strain', 'True Strain'],
   ['(s)', '(mm)', '(N)', '(%)', '(%)']], 
  dtype='|S26')], [array([['Specimen_RawData_1.csv', 'Cycle: 7', '', '', ''],
   ['Time', 'Extension', 'Load', 'Strain', 'True Strain'],
   ['(s)', '(mm)', '(N)', '(%)', '(%)']], 
  dtype='|S26')], [array([['Specimen_RawData_1.csv', 'Cycle: 7', '', '', ''],
   ['Time', 'Extension', 'Load', 'Strain', 'True Strain'],
   ['(s)', '(mm)', '(N)', '(%)', '(%)']], 
  dtype='|S26')], [array([['Specimen_RawData_1.csv', 'Cycle: 7', '', '', ''],
   ['Time', 'Extension', 'Load', 'Strain', 'True Strain'],
   ['(s)', '(mm)', '(N)', '(%)', '(%)']], 
  dtype='|S26')], [array([['Specimen_RawData_1.csv', 'Cycle: 7', '', '', ''],
   ['Time', 'Extension', 'Load', 'Strain', 'True Strain'],
   ['(s)', '(mm)', '(N)', '(%)', '(%)']], 
  dtype='|S26')], [array([['Specimen_RawData_1.csv', 'Cycle: 7', '', '', ''],
   ['Time', 'Extension', 'Load', 'Strain', 'True Strain'],
   ['(s)', '(mm)', '(N)', '(%)', '(%)']], 
  dtype='|S26')]]
```

What am I missing here. Seems like I am misunderstanding something fundamental in lists and arrays. I think I could easily do this with numpy, but I would like to understand what is happening here.

Comment: which temporary you are referring to? please provide the code causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a reference not a copy so you are changing the same object :

```
tempHeader = header # <- reference to object
```

You need to make a `deepcopy` of your lists of lists.

```
from copy import deepcopy
tempHeader = deepcopy(header)  # completely new object
```

You can see when you check the object identity that they both point to the same location in memory:

```
In [17]: l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

In [18]: id(l)
Out[18]: 140365355535048

In [19]: id(l[0])
Out[19]: 140365355537608

In [20]: l1 = l

In [21]: id(l1)
Out[21]: 140365355535048

In [22]: id(l1[0])
Out[22]: 140365355537608
In [23]: l is l1
Out[23]: True
```

Now actually making a copy:

```
In [24]: from copy import  deepcopy

In [25]: l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

In [26]: id(l)
Out[26]: 140365355535688

In [27]: id(l[0])
Out[27]: 140365355559112

In [28]: l1 = deepcopy(l)

In [29]: id(l1)
Out[29]: 140365355561928

In [30]: id(l1[0])
Out[30]: 140365355562824

In [31]: l is l1
Out[31]: False
```

Comment: So when I place tempHeader in the list (newHeader) I am really only placing the reference copy of tempHeader and therefore it keeps chaning?

Comment: @user2236547, you are basically creating pointers to the same object, when it changes all the references change because they all are the same object

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am surprised that I have not ran into  these issues before since I do a lot of nested lists and np arrays.

Comment: No worries,  you are always creating a reference  use foo = bar when it comes to lists and because they are mutable all changes are reflected because manipulation does not create a new object it just changes the original